# How to calculate pixels from inches for printing

Tags: css, printing, media

I would like to allow users to select a fixed paper size and dpi, then generate a div container with an image which have enough width/height that when it's send to a printer with the same settings (same paper size and dpi), it will have the size/quality expected.

As far as I know the formula is quite simple, what I have done:
if user selected  24" x 18"  with 72 dpi
it generates a div container with an image of 1728px x 1296px (24"x 72dpi= 1728px width  and 18"x 72dpi=1296px)

But when I send that div with media print to a printer, even I have the PDF printer with setting 24"x18" x 72dpi, the size is actually smaller than the paper.

is my formula correct?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is directly related to programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For printing purposes, you can define "print styles", which works like media queries (actually it *is* a media query):

```
@media print {
    body {
        background: none;
    }
    .my_wrapper {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 2in auto;
    }
etc.
}
```

In there you can define the sizes for all elements also in absolute units, like centimeter, inches etc. Have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp (at the bottom of that page)

(remember: what's in there, is only valid for the printout)

You can also set page breaks to determine where your web page should be divided into print pages, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp and the following pages.

So, it *is* possible to work out a relatively exact layout for the printouts. But it's a lot of work, and often it's easier just to put a pdf on your site that people can print out.

Comment: Actually I forgot I can use inches as unit in css... that saved me time to trying to compute the pixels by myself...